# Regex to force a specific length and at the same time not starting with a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble building a very complex Regex. These are my constraints:

1. Length: 8 to 10
2. Cannot start by a number neither by an underscore
3. Has at least one capital letter, one number and one character among
   the following 3 special characters: _$£

I thought I did it when I got to this:

```
^([^0-9_])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$£_])[A-Za-z0-9$£_]{7,9}$
```

It correctly fails the 1st statement:

- aDf123_ fails because its length is not 8
- aDf123_aAAFF fails because its length is more than 10

It correctly fails the 2nd statement:

- _aDf1234 fails because it starts with an underscore
- 1aDf1234 fails because it starts with a number

It correctly fails the 3rd statement:

- aaDf1234 fails because it doesn't have any special character
- aadf1$34 fails because it doens't have a capital letter
- aaDf$£££ fails because it doesn't have a number

And finally, it passes through the validation with a valid string: aaDf$££5

What is the problem? The problem is that the following string fails while it should pass through the validation: Daaa$444

When the capital letter is the first letter my regex doesn't see it. How can I make it see it? I know it is related with the fact that my regex ends with {7,9} instead of {8,10} but I cannot help it because I have to define that it must not start with a number or underscore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put lookaheads  after `^` and replace `[^0-9_]` with `[A-Za-z$£]`:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$£_])[A-Za-z$£][A-Za-z0-9$£_]{7,9}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3QcUyL/1).

Else, the first `[^0-9_]` matches `^`, `&`, etc. that is NOT a digit or `_` and the lookaheads only look for the required patterns *after the first char*. **So, any valid string that has a required char only at its beginning will fail.**

Alternatively, turn the `[^0-9_]` into the negative `(?![0-9_])` lookahead (and then you will need to replace the `{7,9}` with `{8,10}` at the end since the lookahead pattern is non-consuming):

```
^(?![0-9_])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$£_])[A-Za-z0-9$£_]{8,10}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJLbU8/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor, that was exactly what I needed! I will not forget to accept your answer on monday.

Comment: @LuisGouveia: ["Don't put off till tomorrow what you can do today."](https://www.google.com/search?q=Don%27t+put+off+till+tomorrow+what+you+can+do+today.&espv=2&biw=1745&bih=864&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwlfGwn4XSAhXsHpoKHT6lAUkQsAQIJQ&dpr=1.1&gws_rd=cr&ei=4YudWJSfK-fa6ASd47qgDw)

Comment: Absolutely Wiktor! I thought I had to wait 48 hours but apparently that is not necessary :)